# Word used for a large cloth that covers a lady’s head and shoulders

Tags: word-request

[image: drawing of a woman with a cloth covering her hair]

What do you call the thing on the lady's head in English?

It isn't scarf, let me tell you. It is a much longer garment than a scarf. It can ever covers shoulder and chest.

Comment: Be careful of saying "it's not a scarf".  The fact you are asking this question implies that you don't know what the range of meanings that native speakers of English have for "scarf".  What I'm saying is, if you don't know what this is called in English, how do you know it is not called a scarf?

Comment: @ James K Why I said ''it's not a scarf'' because the scarf we see usually doesn't have the length that covers shoulders and chest; yet, by your comment what I conclude, not necessarily correct though,  is that a 'scarf' can be long enough to cover shoulders, chest. Please let me know if my conclusions isn't correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be a [**shawl**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shawl).

> **shawl** = a square or oblong usually fabric garment or wrapper used especially as a covering for the head or shoulders

Comment: No it's not a shawl, that is something different. Those using this call it DUPATTA. But what English users call it, is my question.

Comment: Did you try to translate it with a translator / dictionary? What word(s) did you find?

Comment: @xeesid I would call it a shawl... maybe its English name _is_ dupatta though; the English language often just uses foreign words to name things.

Comment: @ James K I've made a research that I'd like to share that the word DUPATTA comes from Sanskrit and is derived in both Urdu and Hindi. The Sanskrit word PAT means 'fold' and 'screen'. The prefix 'DU' refers to 'two' since this garment has two folds or corners, and is used by many Sub-continent women to cover their heads and even sometimes faces.

Comment: @xeesid I think both virolino and James K have correctly given the right answers. Form Wikipedia: *" **Dupatta, Chunari, Chunariya, or Audhani**, is a **shawl-like scarf**, women's traditionally essential clothing from the Indian subcontinent. ... A **ghoonghat (ghunghat, ghunghta, ghumta, odhni, laaj, chunari, jhund) is a headcovering or headscarf**, worn in the Indian subcontinent ... to cover their heads, and often their faces. Generally **aanchal or pallu**, the loose end of a sari is pulled over the head and face to act as a ghunghat. A **dupatta (long scarf)** is ...used as a ghungat. "*

Answer (score 3):

The *specific* word used in English is "[Dupatta](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dupatta)", it is a borrowing from Hindi.  It is quite common for a specific item from a foreign culture not to have any native word in English. In these cases English speakers will freely borrow from other languages, adapting to English pronunciation as appropriate.  Compare this the English words for "A long Japanese dress: *Kimono*", "soft leather shoes similar to those worn by Americans *moccasins*" or "an Indian wrap dress *sari*".

When writing for an audience that may not know much about a specific item of clothing it is common to define the word in a parenthesis:

> The dupatta (a wide headscarf that wraps around the head, neck and shoulders) remains popular with the younger generation of Indian women.

As a less specific, but more widely understandable word "shawl", "headscarf" or "scarf" are all possible terms.

Comment: But if it is TV subtitles, then there is an issue of length.